# mysql between datetime shows wrong record

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT id
     , order_date
     , seat_number
     , cashier_fk
     , branch_fk
     , waiter_fk
     , void
     , total_amount
     , customer_name
     , payment
     , notes
     , down_payment
     , received_date
     , void_reason
     , discount
     , discount_percentage
     , printed
     , done
     , vat
     , service_charge
  FROM order_tbl
 WHERE received_date between "2018-03-15" AND "2018-03-18"
```

but it shows 
My table has this record:

```
id-------order_date
1-------2018-03-09 09:09:25
2-------2018-03-13 18:29:16
3-------2018-03-13 20:00:49
4-------2018-03-13 20:01:46
5-------2018-03-13 20:05:48
6-------2018-03-13 20:06:34
7-------2018-03-13 20:07:15
9-------2018-03-16 19:06:23
10-------2018-03-16 20:22:26
```

But it shows only

```
id-------order_date
5-------2018-03-13 20:05:48
6-------2018-03-13 20:06:34
7-------2018-03-13 20:07:15
9-------2018-03-16 19:06:23
10-------2018-03-16 20:22:26
```

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: Order date <> received date

Answer (score 4):

Do not use `between` with dates or date/times.  The time component throws everything off.

Instead, express the logic as:

```
WHERE received_date >= '2018-03-15' AND
      received_date < '2018-03-19'
```

Note the inequality at the end of the range.  This ensures that you get everything from that date.

Aaron Bertrand has a really good blog post on the subject, [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common).

Comment: Good article from Bertrand...almost qualifies as a rant.  TY for that as I haven't seen that before.

Comment: It still shows the same... record 5-------2018-03-13 20:05:48
6-------2018-03-13 20:06:34
7-------2018-03-13 20:07:15 is still there

Comment: @JemuelElimanco . . . That is very puzzling, then.  What is the data type of `received_date`?

Comment: Perhaps order date and received date are two different things

Comment: The data type of received_date is datetime